# WARNING with ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, adt

I'm running under Windows 7, Eclipse w/ Andriod ADT, NDK and Cygwin.  When I try to build my native code using the ndk-build command, I get this message: "/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml"

Any/all help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should just set `android:minSdkVersion` larger than 14.

Or you can try to set `APP_PLATFORM := android-8` in your Application.mk file. After this I think warning will disappear but you must be sure that your native code satisfies this constraint and will work on the given platform.

Also you can read this documentation for understanding in a future.
http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/STABLE-APIS.html